# Customize 'React Scroll Calendar' - change colors on display and on select

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, calendar, less

I am using the react-scroll-calender npm module in my project and I need to customize the look and feel starting with the colors.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-calendar
```

I found the CSS & less files in 'node-modules/react-scroll-calendar/build/' and made changes to the hex values of the colors but they don't reflect in my localhost.

need help.